# Android 7 - Notification appears with no time

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-7.0-nougat

On Android 7 time doesn't appears on notification.

```
 public static void showAlert(Context context) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlertActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, CODE_NOTIFICATION, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // build notification
    Notification n = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.title_notification))
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.mesage_alert))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_welcome_cap)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setAutoCancel(true).build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(CODE_NOTIFICATION, n);
}
```

This is the code that I'm using.
Does anyone know if in Android 7, the time doesn't appears?

Comment: I have time on my notifications. I use `NotificationCompat` insteaf of `Notification` class (but it should not be different). My code looks like yours.

Comment: Try call `.setShowWhen(true)` with other `Notification` methods. Perhaps you need to call `setWhen(System.getCurrentTimeMillis());` first...